# a function to create multiple plots

Tags: python

I want to create a function in Python so that I just input the name of country and it will create all 4 plots. Basically, a function to replace 4 single codes as below:

```
plt.figure(1)
plotCT(viz1,'Czechia')
plt.figure(2)
plotCT(viz2,'Czechia')
plt.figure(3)
plotCT(viz3,'Czechia')
plt.figure(4)
plotCT(viz4,'Czechia')
```

Do you have any idea for that? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to write a function? If so, did you have a problem? What was it? Do you know how to write functions?

Comment: I am a new Python user. I try to write a function as below: def compare(name):
    for i in range (1,4):
        plt.figure(i)
        plotCT(viz{i}.format(i=i),name). But it does not work

Comment: you have 4 variables, so you cannot do it this way. put them inside a list so you can use the loop to index them

Comment: could you let me know in detail how to put them into a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a function which accepts a list of your `viz` objects and a string country name, then iterates through the list with a `for` loop to plot each item:

```
def generate_figures(country_name, viz_list):

    # Iterates through each viz in viz_list.
    for index, viz in enumerate(viz_list):

       # Plots the given viz element.
       plt.figure(index)
       plotCT(viz, country_name)


generate_figures("Czechia", [viz1, viz2, viz3, viz4])
```

Comment: it works perfectly!!! thank you so much. Btw, could you share how to improve Python skill in a quick way?

Comment: My recommendation is to take a project-focused approach. There are plenty of free online materials to learn the basics of syntax and various libraries, but application is key. Build things, anything, especially things you'll use and iteratively want to improve upon. Even it it already exists, it's practice and it teaches you how to approach other problems. Like learning "Twinkle Twinkle Little Star" on a violin, you can study the music sheet all day long, but unless you actually play it - no matter how badly - you just get really good at reading sheet music.

Answer (score 0):

How about you try putting the values of the variables viz1 all the way to viz4 into a list, something llke this: values_list = [value_of_viz1, ..., value_of_viz4] then iterate over the list each time passing the values as parameters to the plotCT() function.

```
def plot_figures(country, values_list):
    for i in range(len(values_list)):
       plt.figure(i)
       plotCT(values_list[i], country)
```

plot_figures("Country_Name", [value_of_viz1, ..., value_of_viz4])

Comment: plotCT expects a variable, not a string with the name of the variable. This won't work

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work